# Bootstrap 4 - Dropdown Fade In Transition

Tags: twitter-bootstrap, bootstrap-4

I'm trying to make the Bootstrap 4 Dropdown fade in when clicked, however I am unable to achieve this result with using transitions:

```
.dropdown-menu {
    -webkit-transition: 0.25s;
    transition: 0.25s;
}
```

Thanks!

Comment: Post a [mcve] in your question.

Comment: I bet you'll find out soon enough whether or not you're wrong. :-)

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Adding a slide effect to bootstrap dropdown](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12115833/adding-a-slide-effect-to-bootstrap-dropdown)

Comment: @BryanDellinger That is not for Bootstrap 4 :)

Answer (score 2):

```
.dropdown .dropdown-menu{
    display: block; 
    opacity:0;
    -webkit-transition: all 200ms ease-in;
    -moz-transition: all 200ms ease-in;
    -ms-transition: all 200ms ease-in;
    -o-transition: all 200ms ease-in;
    transition: all 200ms ease-in;
 }
 .dropdown:hover .dropdown-menu {
    display: block;
    opacity: 1;
 }
```

Found this on the internet when I was looking for something similar on hover

Answer (score 1):

This is a working fade transition for dropdown in Bootstrap 4:

```
.dropdown-menu.fade {
   display: block;
   opacity: 0;
   pointer-events: none;
}

.show > .dropdown-menu.fade {
   pointer-events: auto;
   opacity: 1;
}
```

Credit: https://stackoverflow.com/a/47986695/1821637

Answer (score 0):

**you can try this. it will also work all the mobile devices**

```
`@include media-breakpoint-up(xl) {
  .dropdown-on-hover {
    &.dropdown {
      .dropdown-menu{
        display: block; 
        visibility: hidden;
        opacity: 0;
        transition: visibility 0s, opacity 0.5s linear;}
      @include hover-focus {
        .dropdown-menu {
          visibility: visible;
          opacity: 1;
        }
      }
    }
  }
}`
```