# Boostrap 4 navbar dropdown fade effect not working in hover

Tags: html, css, bootstrap-4

Dropdown works fine when clicking, but got trouble when trying to make it work when hovering. this was the original Css only code for adding a fade efect from this post [https://stackoverflow.com/a/47986695/9124081](http://this%20post)

```
.dropdown-menu.fade {
       display: block;
       opacity: 0;
       pointer-events: none;
    }

    .show > .dropdown-menu.fade {
       pointer-events: auto;
       opacity: 1;
    }
```

And this is what I tried for hover, failing miserably

```
.dropdown:hover>.dropdown-menu.fade {
       display: block;
       opacity: 0;
       pointer-events: none;
    }

    .show > .dropdown:hover>.dropdown-menu.fade {
       pointer-events: auto;
       opacity: 1;
    }
```

codepen example: https://codepen.io/anon/pen/LrZxPr

Comment: Doesn't help if you don't include 5he markup.

Answer (score 0):

Don't include the ".show" selector, as that is only applied onclick. Also drop your first rule-set and just use this:

```
.dropdown:hover>.dropdown-menu.fade {            
 display:block;
 opacity: 1;
}
```

Comment: Thanks for answering. Unfortunately, this piece of code make fade effect not work. Please see updated fiddle

Comment: I dont see the fade working at the moment anyway... For opacity to transition the element cant be set to display:none. So you need to set the dropdown to display:block first.. Try this: .dropdown>.dropdown-menu {
  display: block;
}
.dropdown>.dropdown-menu {
  opacity: 0;
  transition: all .3s ease;
}
.dropdown-menu.show,
.dropdown:hover>.dropdown-menu {
  opacity: 1;
}

Comment: There is a problem with that code, when you hover under the dropdown it activates the dropdown menu. Never mine I just used this and works like a charm, is more code but so be it, is only css https://stackoverflow.com/a/15509447/9124081

Comment: Ok. If you add overflow:  hidden to the dropdown and change that to visible on hover it should also work. .dropdown {
  overflow:hidden;
}
.dropdown:hover {
  overflow:visible;
}