# Using Bootstrap 3, how can I make dropdown menus expand with the same animation that the mobile toggle uses?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, twitter-bootstrap

By default, the mobile toggle expands to reveal the menu with a slideout animation. I want the dropdown menus to open using the same animation.

I was able to get close by changing their classes from .dropdown-menu to .collapse as shown [here](http://getbootstrap.com/javascript/#collapse), but this requires me to set a different ID for each dropdown which I'm trying to avoid. Is there any way to add the animation without having to create separate IDs?

Comment: The solution [here](http://stackoverflow.com/a/19339162/353696) did work perfectly for sliding the dropdown menu DOWN, but sliding back up is broken. The slide up isn't smooth, it's very choppy and overlaps the menu items below while sliding up.

Comment: My apologies, I found a response a couple clicks deep that had the solution. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/26267207/bootstrap-3-dropdown-slidedown-strange-behavior-when-navbar-collapsed