# bootstrap 4 beta 2 slideUp slideDown dropdown

Tags: javascript, jquery, bootstrap-4

My goal is to use the jquery functions `slideUp()` and `slideDown()` on the **bootstrap dropdown** element for get a more beautiful slide effect when showing it. I'm using **Bootstrap 4 beta-2**. I searched on Stackoverflow for my problem and **[this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12115833/adding-a-slide-effect-to-bootstrap-dropdown)** was the best result that I found.

I tried the code but nothing works, it seems like my HTML element gets with jQuery is not correctly transformed in jQuery object and for this reason, I can't use jQuery function.

Here is my code:

```
  <nav class="navbar navbar fixed-top navbar-expand-lg navbar-light bg-secondary">
    <button class="navbar-toggler" type="button" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#navbarSupportedContent" aria-controls="navbarSupportedContent" aria-expanded="false" aria-label="Toggle navigation">
      <span class="navbar-toggler-icon text-light"></span>
    </button>
    <a class="navbar-brand text-light tangerine d-block d-lg-none mx-auto" href="#">Site title</a>

    <div class="collapse navbar-collapse" id="navbarSupportedContent">
      <ul class="navbar-nav mx-auto">
        <li id="dropdown-catalogo" class="nav-item dropdown">
          <a class="nav-link dropdown-toggle text-light tangerine" href="#" id="navbarDropdown" role="button" data-toggle="dropdown" aria-haspopup="true" aria-expanded="false">
            dropdown element
          </a>
          <div id="dropdown-menu-catalogo" class="dropdown-menu" aria-labelledby="navbarDropdown">
            <a class="dropdown-item" href="#">element 1</a>
            <a class="dropdown-item" href="#">element 2</a>
            <a class="dropdown-item" href="#">element 3</a>
          </div>
        </li>
        <li class="nav-item">
          <a class="nav-link text-light tangerine" href="#">Contatti</a>
        </li>
        <li class="nav-item d-none d-lg-block">
          <a class="navbar-brand text-light tangerine" href="#">Site name</a>
        </li>
        <li class="nav-item">
          <a class="nav-link text-light tangerine" href="#">Codici miniati</a>
        </li>
        <li class="nav-item">
          <a class="nav-link text-light tangerine" href="#">Eventi</a>
        </li>
      </ul>
    </div>
  </nav>
```

And there is my js on that page:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
  $('#carosello').slick({
    infinite: false,
    slidesToShow: 2,
    slidesToScroll: 1,
    dots: true,
    responsive: [
    {
      breakpoint: 700,
      settings: {
        slidesToShow: 1,
        slidesToScroll: 1,
        infinite: false,
        dots: true
      }
    },
    {
      breakpoint: 450,
      settings: {
        slidesToShow: 1,
        slidesToScroll: 1,
        infinite: false,
        dots: false
      }
    }
    ]
  });

  $('#carosello-grosso').slick({
    infinite: false,
    speed: 500,
    fade: true,
    cssEase: 'linear',
    autoplay: true,
    autoplaySpeed: 3000,
  });

  var viewer = new Viewer(document.getElementById('carosello'));
  var viewerGrosso = new Viewer(document.getElementById('carosello-grosso'));

  if (window.innerWidth < 768) {
    console.log('Vengo attivato');
    $('#da-centrare').addClass('mx-auto');
  } else {
    $('#da-centrare').removeClass('mx-auto');
  }

  $(window).resize(function() {
    if (window.innerWidth < 768) {
      console.log('Vengo attivato');
      $('#da-centrare').addClass('mx-auto');
    } else {
      $('#da-centrare').removeClass('mx-auto');
    }
  });

  $('.dropdown').on('show.bs.dropdown', function() {
    $(this).find('.dropdown-menu').first().stop(true, true).slideDown();
  });

  // Add slideUp animation to Bootstrap dropdown when collapsing.
  $('.dropdown').on('hide.bs.dropdown', function() {
    $(this).find('.dropdown-menu').first().stop(true, true).slideUp();
  });
```

And this is the error that I get:

```
Uncaught TypeError: $(...).find(...).first(...).stop is not a function
    at HTMLLIElement.<anonymous> (indexScript.js:58)
    at HTMLLIElement.dispatch (jquery-3.2.1.slim.min.js:3)
    at HTMLLIElement.q.handle (jquery-3.2.1.slim.min.js:3)
    at Object.trigger (jquery-3.2.1.slim.min.js:3)
    at HTMLLIElement.<anonymous> (jquery-3.2.1.slim.min.js:3)
    at Function.each (jquery-3.2.1.slim.min.js:2)
    at r.fn.init.each (jquery-3.2.1.slim.min.js:2)
    at r.fn.init.trigger (jquery-3.2.1.slim.min.js:3)
    at a.g.toggle (dropdown.js:142)
    at HTMLAnchorElement.<anonymous> (dropdown.js:293)
```

In HTML code I showed just the interesting part because is a long page. if you need more details about it tell me in the comment and I will update the code. While in JS file I showed all because I thought was more important.

Comment: can you add this to jsfiddle? so that it will be easier to test

Comment: @Znaneswar Solved already! But thanks for the interest!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

My best guess is since you are using slim version of jQuery it don't have all features. Use the full version.

```
<script
  src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.2.1.min.js"
  integrity="sha256-hwg4gsxgFZhOsEEamdOYGBf13FyQuiTwlAQgxVSNgt4="
  crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
```

Below is the comment from the slim version with the features removed

```
/*! jQuery v3.2.1 -ajax,-ajax/jsonp,-ajax/load,-ajax/parseXML,-ajax/script,-ajax/var/location,-ajax/var/nonce,-ajax/var/rquery,-ajax/xhr,-manipulation/_evalUrl,-event/ajax,-effects,-effects/Tween,-effects/animatedSelector | (c) JS Foundation and other contributors | jquery.org/license */
```

**[Slim build](https://blog.jquery.com/2016/06/09/jquery-3-0-final-released/)**

> Finally, we’ve added something new to this release. Sometimes you
>   don’t need ajax, or you prefer to use one of the many standalone
>   libraries that focus on ajax requests. And often it is simpler to use
>   a combination of CSS and class manipulation for all your web
>   animations. Along with the regular version of jQuery that includes the
>   ajax and effects modules, we’re releasing a “slim” version that
>   excludes these modules. All in all, it excludes ajax, effects, and
>   currently deprecated code. The size of jQuery is very rarely a load
>   performance concern these days, but the slim build is about 6k gzipped
>   bytes smaller than the regular version – 23.6k vs 30k.