# How to implement dropdown animation in React-Bootstrap?

Tags: reactjs, react-bootstrap

The native dropdown from React-Bootstrap is very choppy. I would like to smooth it out. I found this class for plain Bootstrap and am wondering how I would port it over to React, or just accomplish something similar:

https://startbootstrap.com/snippets/animated-navbar-dropdown/

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I used MadisonTrash's answer here: https://stackoverflow.com/a/32233048/4700234

I also added the `<NativeListener>` component from `react-native-listener`'s in order to prevent clicking the dropdown's header from toggling the dropdown:

```
<NativeListener stopClick>
    <NavDropdown>
        ...
    </NavDropdown>
</NativeListener>
```